# IIS Stuck in SendResponse state

Tags: asp-classic, com, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a classic VB6 ASP application compiled into dll's and executed through COM. The web site pulls from a SQLServer database.

One particular function builds a page by getting data rows, and then for each data row queries the database again to build rows in a sub table.

The problem is that if this page is large, and if the request for the page comes from a remote machine, then the IIS server gets stuck in the SendResponse state and never sends the page. If I call that same page using the same dataset, but call it from a browser running on the server itself, the page is quickly built and rendered. If I modify the sqlquery so that fewer rows are returned and the page is smaller, all clients can quickly load and render

I think I've confirmed that even when the page hangs the sql queries complete quickly and the COM objects have completed building the page.

I have a test server where I can test exact copies of the application but I haven't been able to find a setting in IIS or the apps web.config files that will duplicate the issue.

Is there something at the OS network layer I should be checking?

Comment: Why doing a query for each result?
This may be a buffer limit issue.  Try to add `response.flush` or increase buffer size.   There a lot of post on this, like this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968006/response-buffer-limit-exceeded